# How to use Tkinter Scale to bind and display Pandas DataFrame column in Matplotlib Chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter, scale

I am building a data display GUI, using Tkinter (here stripped down). The goal is to use a Tkinter Scale slider to select and move between columns in a Pandas Dataframe, and display the selected column of data as an embedded MatplotLib chart.
However I am having huge trouble binding the Scale slider to selection of the Pandas DataFrame column and the chart display.
With an event from the Tkinter Scale (S1), the called Function (fromScale) should be updating the Class variable (displayField), which then updates the string (dField), which is the column index in the Pandas DataFrame (dar_MAST) for display in the embedded chart.
Any assistance in redefining the binding to allow movement of the Scale slider to allow ‘scrolling’ through the columns of displayed dataframe data would be hugely appreciated, before I go insane here…
(using Python 3.6.5, PyCharm)
Thanks in advance

Have tried numerous configurations of Tkinter 'bindings', and command functions, Global variables versus Class variables, but none work.  Settled with using Class variable here, but still cannot update chart display

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

class dar(Frame):
    displayField = 0   # Class variable to identify the column in the dataframe to display

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('dar_FN')
        content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3, 3, 3, 3))

        dField = 'Fld_' + str(dar.displayField)  # Column index for dataframe display

        datas = np.random.uniform(size=(100, 10))  # Dummy random dataset
        dar_MAST = pd.DataFrame(datas, columns=['Fld_0', 'Fld_1', 'Fld_2', 'Fld_3', 'Fld_4', 'Fld_5', 'Fld_6', 'Fld_7',
                                                'Fld_8', 'Fld_9'])

        frame6 = ttk.Notebook(content, width=465, height=150)   # Frame containing Scale Slider
        frame6_tab1 = ttk.Frame(frame6)
        frame6.add(frame6_tab1, text='tp Selection')
        frame6_tab1_canvas = tk.Canvas(frame6_tab1, width=464, height=145)  # creates MAX canvas in tab
        frame6.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame6.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame6_tab1_canvas.grid(column=20, row=60)

        S1 = Scale(frame6_tab1_canvas, from_=0, to=9, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=360,   # THE SCALE SLIDER
                   highlightcolor='lightblue', tickinterval=100, command=self.fromScale)
        S1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=10)

        self.update_idletasks()

        frame1a = ttk.Notebook(content, width=480, height=750)   # Frame containing data display
        frame1a_tab1 = ttk.Frame(frame1a)
        frame1a.add(frame1a_tab1, text='1a')
        frame1a_tab1_canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1a_tab1, width=470, height=745)
        frame1a_tab1_canvas.grid(column=0, row=20, sticky='nsew')
        frame1a_tab1_chart = plt.figure(figsize=(4.55, 7.46), dpi=100)
        f1at1 = plt.subplot2grid((20, 25), (0, 0), rowspan=20, colspan=25)
        f1at1.grid(True)
        f1at1.set_ylim(0, 100, auto=False)

        f1at1.plot(dar_MAST[dField], dar_MAST[dField].index, linewidth=1, label=dField)
        f1at1.legend()

        canvas_f1at1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(frame1a_tab1_chart, frame1a_tab1_canvas)
        canvas_f1at1.draw()
        canvas_f1at1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
        frame1a.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=1, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
        frame6.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=3, rowspan=1, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
        root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def fromScale(self, val):   # Function to update Class displayField value from Scale Slider event
        dar.displayField = int(val)  # Update Class variable displayField

root = Tk()
app = dar(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Each movement of the Scale slider should change the displayed data chart to the next or relevant column of data in the dar_MAST dataframe, but only the first column data are displayed, ie: no binding?